# JSX is getting converted to React.DOM is not a function - webpack babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am new to webpack and babel. My aim is to write an angularjs directive using ReactJS for rendering. However, when I try to place a react element, webpack converts the element to React.DOM and complains React.DOM is not a function.

```
ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />),element[0]); //gets converted to 
ReactDOM.render(React.DOM(ListContainer, null), element[0]);
```

```
TypeError: **React.DOM** is not a function
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "exports-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.40.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.3",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.3",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.3",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
}
```

**.babelrc**  -

```
{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]}
```

Any help would be appreciated

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8iw6.png)

Comment: How do you intend () to be rendered? Can you include your babel config?

Comment: Hello Charles, I had problem with rendering of html tag in stackoverflow editor. 
Will include babel config

Comment: Yeah, jsx tags won't work as a code snippet. You can still type them out using the code tag ({} in the editor). JSON too.

Comment: @CharlesBamford: Can you show an example ?
The problem is that webpack is throwing this error at runtime. Editor works fine. Image has more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever is looking for answer here. I was using `/** @jsx React.Dom */` with newer version of react. Once I remove this, everything works magically. This post from https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/180 helped.